# Android - where does alpha value go in values folder?

Tags: android, android-layout

Say i have an `xml` element like this:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/login_background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:alpha="0.2">
```

i want that alpha value `0.2` to be a variable. What is the "Android way" of making the value a variable? do i stick it in `dimen.xml`? or does it even matter?

Would a proper way to do this be that i just create a file called `transparency.xml` and then link it with `android:alpha="@transparency/my_value"` ?

Answer (score 13):

You could do it as:

```
<resources>
    <item name="alpha_value" format="float" type="dimen">0.2</item>
</resources>
```

This way `alpha_value` will be in `@dimen/` folder.

For more info, see the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html).

Answer (score 2):

Since `android:alpha` takes integer types only, we will have to define it in `dimens.xml` as an `item` with `integer` type and `float` format, as follows:

```
<item name="alpha_login" type="integer" format="float">0.2</item>
```

Now it can be used just like an `integer` resource.

Use it in your layout file as:

```
android:alpha="@integer/alpha_login"
```

Use it in your code as:

```
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
resources.getValue(R.integer.alpha_login, typedValue, true);
float alphaLogin = typedValue.getFloat();
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me

in `dimens.xml`:

```xml
<resources>
  <item name="alpha_value" type="integer" format="float">0.8</item>
</resources>
```

In a layout:

```
  ...
  android:alpha="@integer/alpha_value"
  ...
```

In a code:

```
  R.integer.alpha_value
```